# Match Route and Direction On the basis of latitude and longitude

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, latitude-longitude, google-latitude

When travelling from Point A to Point D  we are currently saving all route latitude and longitude in our database.

from this data we are able to find the requests near 100 meter radius by calculating distance between two latitude and logitude

But now we want to match the route of person travelling from C to D in same direction and don't want to show the requests who are travelling in opposite direction i.e from D to A or D to C.